# Dimension of the total ring of fractions of a reduced ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative reduced ring (need not be noetherian). Let $S$ be the set of all non-zerodivisors of $A$. What is the Krull dimension of $S^{-1}A$ ?

Comment: In the Noetherian case I think it is $1$, as the zero-divisors are the union of a finite set of minimal prime ideals.

Comment: @AlexBecker You are wrong: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51400/the-total-ring-of-fractions-of-a-reduced-noetherian-ring

Comment: @YACP I meant to say $0$. I believe that is the case.

Answer (score 7):

A concrete example. Let $k$ be a field and let 
$$A=k[X_1, \dots, X_n, \dots]/(X_iX_j)_{i\ne j}=k[x_1, \dots, x_n, \dots].$$ 
It is reduced, its maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ is the set of the zerodivisors. Hence $S=A\setminus\mathfrak m$ and $S^{-1}A=A_{\mathfrak m}$. But $A_{\mathfrak m}$ has dimension $\ge 1$ (in fact equal to $1$) because $(x_2, \dots, x_n, ...)$ generate a prime ideal in $A$ strictly contained in $\mathfrak m$.

Comment: For an example of dimension n, we can take quotient of A_m by the ideal generated by x_i.x_j with i,j different and j>n. Then p=(x_{n+1},x_{n+2},...) is a prime ideal and we have a chain of prime ideals p,(p,x_1),(p,x_1,x_2),...,(p,x_1,...,x_n)=m.

Comment: @manoj I guess your example is in fact the quotient of $k[X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots]$ by the ideal $(X_iX_j:i\neq j \text{ and } j>n)$. However, the existence of a chain of prime ideals of length $n$ can prove only that the height of $m$ is at least $n$, not necessarily equal to $n$. (However, in this case it's true that the height of $m$ is $n$.)

Comment: We saw that the dimension of total quotient ring Q(A) of a reduced ring need not be zero. I was trying to prove that it is zero (I was wrong) since I want to know whether finitely generated projective modules of constant rank over Q(A) are free. Over a zero dimensional ring, we know that all finitely generated projective modules of constant rank are free. So my original question over Q(A) remains to be answered. Any answer!

Answer (score 6):

This is just a remark.

In the noetherian case one knows that $\dim Q(A)=0$. (Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51400/the-total-ring-of-fractions-of-a-reduced-noetherian-ring) for a proof.) But in general this is not true. Assume that $\dim Q(A)=0$. Since $Q(A)$ is reduced, it follows that $Q(A)$ is von Neumann regular. But there are [examples](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1971__99_/BSMF_1971__99__265_0/BSMF_1971__99__265_0.pdf) of (non-noetherian) reduced rings (with compact minimal spectrum) such that their total ring of fractions is not von Neumann regular.

Comment: However, if $A$ is reduced and its minimal spectrum is finite, then $Q(A)$ is von Neumann regular.