# Total ring of fractions of non-noetherian reduced ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As is known, see [The total ring of fractions of a reduced Noetherian ring is a direct product of fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51400/the-total-ring-of-fractions-of-a-reduced-noetherian-ring-is-a-direct-product-of)
if the ring $A$ is noetherian and reduced, we can show that the total ring of fractions must be a direct product of fields, however in the case of non-noetherian, what can be said? Must it be krull dimension 0? Must it be a product (of arbitrarily many) fields? I think it must be no for the second question but I don't know many constructions for non-noetherian rings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the first question, no.

For a reduced ring $R$, being $0$-dimensional is equivalent to being Von Neumann Regular.  It is well known that the total quotient ring of a reduced ring is VNR iff the minimal spectrum of $R$ is compact and $R$ has the property that f.g. ideals consist of zero divisors iff they have nonzero annihilators.

See [this nice paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256046365) of Matlis, in particular 1.15. This makes it easy to construct examples of reduced rings which don't have $0$-dimensional total ring of fractions.

This also settles the second question, since VNRs can be equivalently characterized as subdirect products of fields.

It would be a little misleading to end the answer there, though.  There *is* a canonical embedding of any reduced ring in a $0$-dimensional 'fraction-like ring.' This is typically approached in one of two equivalent ways:  (1) by characterizing the total ring of fractions as a direct limit of the modules $\text{Hom}(d, R)$ where $d$ is a regular element, and then generalizing that to a direct limit of the modules $\text{Hom}(D, R)$ where $D$ is a dense ideal of $R$, or (2) as the injective envelope of $R$.  These constructions work also for noncommutative rings, and when $R$ is non-singular (i.e. its elements have non-essential annihilators,
equivalent to being reduced for commutative rings) you can actually put a ring structure on these module constructions, and this yields a self-injective Von Neumann Regular ring.

(For commutative rings, the first approach is detailed in the first chapter of these [great notes](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/fgl.pdf), or for the noncommutative case I'd recommend looking in T.Y. Lam's Lecture's on Modules and Rings. For the injective envelope approach, again Matlis' paper is helpful.)

Comment: Do you have a citation handy for the claim in the second paragraph characterizing VNR total quotient rings? I was only aware of Johnson's theorem on the maximal quotient ring, and I'm interested.

Comment: That characterization is proposition 1.15 in Matlis.  The result is originally due to Yann Quentel, https://eudml.org/doc/87167, an otherwise obscure French mathematician.

Comment: Thank you!!! Glad to find this...

Comment: My pleasure, glad to have been of use

Answer (score 1):

A commutative Noetherian reduced ring is a Goldie ring, and so it has a semisimple classical ring of quotients. Therefore the ring of quotients is a finite product of fields.

This extends the non-Noetherian case slightly because there are non-Noetherian Goldie rings.

In general, the maximal ring of quotients $Q_{max}(R)$ for a reduced ring is von Neumann regular and self-injective. Since $R$ is commutative, its classical ring of quotients embeds in this ring. There are a couple conditions that can ensure the two rings of quotients are equal: one is when every dense ideal contains a regular element, and a stronger one, I think, is the ACC on annihilator ideals.

Otherwise, the classical ring of quotients may not be so well behaved.

Comment: Uh how does this extend in non noetherian case?

Comment: @davik Sorry, I neglected to give the appropriate emphasis that you asked for.